# combining AND operator in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to combine conditions by AND operator ..

in my query i want to combine 3 coditions where the result appears when all of them are true.

i want to achive this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'condition1' AND ('condition2' AND 'condition3');
```

i tried this combination but it doesnt work.

this is the actual code

```
SELECT * FROM planmenu WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND type LIKE '%$type%' AND dishcontent LIKE '%$dishcontent%'
```

where
$search, $type and $dishcontent are php variables. however when i place OR insteade of the second AND it works perfectly. but when i use AND it does not !!

Comment: You don't need the parentheses.  Your statement is correct, assuming that you are actually replacing 'condition1' with something like column='value'

Comment: You have to give the conditions a value? `condition1='what'`

Comment: The pseudocode above looks correct (besides the fact you have string literals instead of conditions, of course). Could you share your actual code and explain why it doesn't act like you'd expect?

Comment: Please post your exact query as is, because it is too hard to determine what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your SQL.  Check your data.

```
create table planmenu ( 
  name varchar(20),
  type varchar(20),
  dishcontent varchar(20)
);

insert into planmenu values ('a','b','c');
```

Now if you do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM planmenu 
WHERE name LIKE '%z%' 
AND type LIKE '%z%' 
AND dishcontent LIKE '%c%';
```

You'll get zero records back because there are no records matching all three conditions.

If you do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM planmenu 
WHERE name LIKE '%z%' 
AND type LIKE '%z%' 
OR dishcontent LIKE '%c%';
```

You'll get a record back because the OR makes it so that the first two conditions OR only the third condition has to be true.  It is the equivalent of running this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM planmenu 
WHERE (name LIKE '%z%' AND type LIKE '%z%')
OR dishcontent LIKE '%c%';
```

Check your data.  You don't have any records matching all three conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition to the columns you want to query against, with the values you are trying to get.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM table
WHERE 
condition1='something' AND 
condition2='somethingelse' AND 
condition3='somethingdifferent';
```